# Android Gradle Compatibility

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on Android multimodule project with buildSrc and kotlin dsl.
The relevant files are below,

`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0")
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2")
}


val compileKotlin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

`Project/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") apply false
    id("com.android.library") apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

`app/build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

`settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "TEST"
include(":app")
```

My concern here is, in my project level build.gradle file

`id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.0" apply false`

Giving explicit version to any of the plugins not just this, gives the following issue

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.9.0', apply: false]
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.
```

But if I use without version it works.
I am not sure its because I used buildSrc, and I am wondering how it works without giving version, any documentation link explaining this will be helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/20084 does it help?

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies in buildSrc will apply to all module, so remove `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.0" apply false` is safe.

Comment: But all dependencies are not present in buildSrc.